# Why is a specific route restricted to vehicle height 400cm?

Tags: here-api

This specific route doesn't work when height is set to 420cm:

```
https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?
jsonAttributes=41
&waypoint0=53.94499,10.85676
&waypoint1=41.59747,-4.72606
&currency=EUR
&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled
&legAttributes=none
&tollVehicleType=3
&trailerType=2
&trailersCount=1
&vehicleNumberAxles=3
&trailerNumberAxles=2
&tiresCount=10
&hybrid=0
&emissionType=6
&fuelType=diesel
&height=420cm
&trailerHeight=420cm
&length=1650cm
&width=255cm
&heightAbove1stAxle=100cm
&vehicleWeight=12000kg
&limitedWeight=40000kg
&commercial=1
&driver_cost=1000
&vehicle_cost=1
&app_id=
&app_code=
```

The api returns an error:

```
{"issues":[{"message":"Couldn't reach way point 1 (start links 1208480385 -1208480385  dest links 564534255 -564534255 ), link 1208480385's through traffic restriction might apply"},{"message":"Request id: cbf5e720-a40e-45fe-9c87-cb92c39d3b85"}],"response":null,"error_id":"cbf5e720-a40e-45fe-9c87-cb92c39d3b85","response_code":"400 Bad Request"}
```

Setting both height parameters to 400cm instead makes it work.

I've tried to check truck restrictions along the route but couldn't find any, for that I used this mapping example provided by Here [Fleet Telematics API](https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/fleet_telematics_api) and checked the "Truck restrictions" checkbox

Can you tell where the restriction is for this specific route?

Comment: please check the docs for the limits https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html and also you can check the truck restriction on the https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/fleet_telematics_api but zooming the map to . 2km.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I think it fails with 420cm height because many countries in Europe has a default height restriction of 400cm, while we in Finland have 420cm. So just using 400cm height for this specific route should be ok.